# C# Windows Forms scroll flicker issue

Tags: c#, graphics, flicker

Here's a preview:

[Video Preview of flicker](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/169726586931773440/1059798150900097055/2023-01-03_15-38-34.mp4)

Code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WinBlur;
using static WinBlur.UI;

namespace MiTA
{
    public partial class MiTA : Form
    {
        public MiTA()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
            UpdateStyles();

            Refresh();

            CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;

        }

        protected override void OnScroll(ScrollEventArgs se)
        {
            this.Invalidate();

            base.OnScroll(se);

            base.DoubleBuffered = true;

            SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
            UpdateStyles();

            base.OnScroll(se);

        }

        private const int CS_DROPSHADOW = 0x00020000;

        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
                cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;

                return cp;

                cp.ClassStyle |= CS_DROPSHADOW;
                return cp;
            }
        }

        private void MiTA_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void MiTA_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetBlurStyle(cntrl: this, blurType: BlurType.Mica, designMode: Mode.DarkMode);
        }

        private void label1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            guna2ImageButton2.ImageSize = new Size(43, 43);
        }

        private void label1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            guna2ImageButton2.ImageSize = new Size(42, 42);
        }

        private void skglControl1_PaintSurface(object sender, SkiaSharp.Views.Desktop.SKPaintGLSurfaceEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I know that C# WinForms uses GDI+ which is extremely crappy, but I'm sure there is a solution to this.

Edit: Adding the code of custom UserControls below

I used `Guna2PictureBox` instead of `PictureBox`, since nothing changed so I needed it to be a bit more custom since Guna2PictureBox has properties like `BorderRadius`, `ImageRotate`.

```cs
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MiTA
{
    public class MiTAPictureBox : Guna.UI2.WinForms.Guna2PictureBox
    {

        public MiTAPictureBox()
        {
            DoubleBuffed = true;
            ResizeRedraw = true;
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |
                          ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        }

    }
}
```

`MiTAPanel`:

```cs
using Guna.UI2.WinForms;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MiTA
{
    public partial class MiTAPanel : Guna2Panel
    {

        public MiTAPanel() : base()
        {
            DoubleBuffed = true;
            ResizeRedraw = true;
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |
                          ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        }
    }

}
```

I've tried everything with controls too.

Comment: Are you sure it's a flicker issue? From the video I'm not 100% sure but it kind of looks more like a lag issue than a flicker issue. Lag can happen if there is a lot of graphics to be rendered. Also, in your code, why do you call `Invalidate()` from `OnScroll(...)` and also you are calling `base.OnScroll(se)` twice? As a start, I'd remove the _OnScroll()_ override and put all those settings in the constructor instead. Also, does it happen in your app only? If it happens to other apps, it might be an issue with drivers.

Comment: GDI+ is not crappy nor is it slow. You should not call SetStyle outside your forms constructor, that is bad design and changes stuff after the handle is created, in your case it changes native style properties even after the form is shown, which is a bad idea. Your `Refresh()` call in the ctor does nothing at that stage and should be removed. Your call to `UpdateStyles()` in the ctor is useless as well as you only need to call it after the Forms handle is created which happens way after the constructor is called. How are all those images added to your form?

Comment: @Max and Leandro I've taken both of your advices and removed the Style stuff outside of the constructor, I've also removed the OnScroll & Invalidate. It's less laggy, but more flickery. I'm not sure what to do. Do you have any advice/solution(s)? Also, these images are from the Guna2PictureBox control.

Comment: @Pronner Double buffer all container controls like panels and picture boxes. I don't know `Guna2PictureBox` but I'd recommend removing it and creating your own controls. If you just want to display images you really don't need any external libraries or projects. If you load any images from disk, then cache them in a memory cache to dramatically reduce load time when the need to be reloaded while moving through your form.

Comment: @Max What if I made a UserControl and changed the class into a Guna2PictureBox and made it double buffered? Would it work? Also, can you provide appropriate code of how to double buffer a control without causing lag or issues?

Comment: @Pronner You just derive from PictureBox and set the DoubleBuffered property to true within the constructor. Deriving a UserControl from a custom control won't work unless it's a UserControl as well. Test your Form with normal .Net controls and not with any of the Guna2 controls and check if the flickering/lag changes, if so you know that those controls are laggy. Deriving controls is a very basic practice when creating your own GUI so I recommend you spend some time looking into that and try building your GUI without any external libraries for now.

Comment: @Max I tried this, and it still does the same thing. Any other solutions?

Comment: @Pronner Can't help with the provided code. You need to show how your images are loaded. Your code above does not show how your images are added. Does it lag without images? If yes, your WinBlur is the source of lag.

Comment: @Max I've provided a link to the video. "Video Preview of flicker".

Comment: @Pronner Without seeing your code that actually deals with the images I can't help you. The Video does not help

Comment: @Max You mean the PictureBox & Panel that I make for the GUI?

Comment: @Pronner Yes, but primarily how the images are loaded...

Comment: @Max Done. I've provided code of the Controls. You also have the video like I said, and it's still the same. I've tried PictureBox instead of Guna2PictureBox but it was the same so I switched to Guna2PictureBox.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to **switch to WPF**, and depending on your situation you should/should not switch to WPF. In general, WPF provides a lot more customizability and graphic to your application meaning there won't be flickering whatsoever and possibly no lag at all, and it's newer than WinForms, you can say. It also includes many more features than Windows Forms does.

If you're making a simple app like a **Calculator** for example, it's best to stay on Windows Forms, it'll take a lot less time and it will be easier to make.

If you're making a complex app like an **IDE/Code Editor/2D Game/other**, you should definitely switch to WPF.

It wasn't easy to for me to switch, because I thought it would be very hard and I didn't really like how it used **XML**/**XAML**. But I can say this with heart that I did not look back at all after making the switch. As someone who used WinForms for 3 years, I am proud to have switched to WPF.

For the XML issue, You can always use the **designer**, since WPF has one too. It's not recommended, since sometimes it can cause issues, but it's your choice.

```cs
this.DoubleBuffer = true
```

^^ This is currently the easiest fix, however it's not considered a fix for complex applications that may lag/have a lot of UI.